# Is there a way to programmatically change a maps center using maplace.js?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following function in a maplace.js based instantiation for my map. I would like to dynamically change the map's center after the user scrolls to a position in the map. This is what I have so far:

```
maplace = new Maplace({
    map_div: '#gmap-list',
    styles: styles,
    scrollwheel: false,
    controls_type: 'list',
    controls_on_map: false,
    controls_title: 'Choose a location:',
    locations: LocsB,
    map_options: {
        scrollwheel: false,
        set_center: [45.9, 10.9]
    },
    afterCreateMarker: function(index, location, marker) {
        $(window).scroll( function() { 
            var scrolled_val = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf();
            if (scrolled_val < 1027) {
                if (marker.lat == -26.243254) {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
                }
            } else {
                console.log(scrolled_val);
                setCenter({lat: 42.346268, lng: -71.095764}); // does not work
            }
        });
    }
}).Load();
```

Thank you for everyone's help!

Comment: Did you look here? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction or here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning